# Toast message not displaying

Tags: android, android-asynctask, toast, android-toast

In the next code I can not make the toast message inside the doInBackground method jump.

When I delete this line, the writing of the "error" string into the edittext performed fine.

What am I doing wrong?

```
private class Verify extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {    

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
  }   

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    username = etusername.getText().toString();
    password = etpass.getText().toString();   

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));   

    String response = null;
    String result;    

    try {
      response = CustumHttpClient.executeHttpPost(url_verify_detials, postParameters);
      result = response.toString();
      result = result.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
      if (!result.equals("0")) {
        Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, danpage.class);
        startActivity(in);
      } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
        etusername.setText("Error");
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
  }   

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't place any code which does anything to the user interface inside the doInBackground method. If you want to show your toast you will need to return a result to onPostExecute and deal with it there.

How do you return a result to onPostExecute? In your class definition the third parameter inside the <> is the type that you will want to return in the onPostExecute method so you declaration will look like

```
 private class Verify extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
```

and you onPostExecute will look like

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
```

Please see the reference for a good example. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: When I do that, my return value Void in doInBackground method marked with an error

Comment: Sorry. Also change that to String and make sure you return your 'result' variable at the end of doInBackground.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `publishProgress` and `onProgressUpdate` to make a `Toast`:

```
private static final int ERROR = -1;
...
try {
  response = CustumHttpClient.executeHttpPost(url_verify_detials, postParameters);
  result = response.toString();
  result = result.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
  if (!result.equals("0")) {
    Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, danpage.class);
    startActivity(in);
  } else {
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    //    .show();
    //etusername.setText("Error");
    publishProgress(ERROR);
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
...

@Override protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
super.onProgressUpdate(values);
if (values[0]==ERROR){
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "this is my Toast message!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
      .show();
  etusername.setText("Error");
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You must use runOnUIThread method to execute this code.

You must execute ui methods in that thread.

Comment: using `runOnUiThread()` from `doInBackground()` defeats the purpose of using `AsyncTask`

Comment: It depends on what is the purpose of Async task. When you only want to show Toast when exception occured and you Async Task is using return value for more important logic - you don't mess your whole logic just to show a simple toast. There is nothing wrong about using runOnUIThread in Async task. It all depends what your code is doing.

Comment: Actually the best answer for this whole question would be... Don't use the AsyncTask because you don't need it. Use a normal thread started on some executor and use runOnUiThread in your else for toast.

Comment: Using a Thread correctly is not a simple task. If care is not taken Threads can lead to leaks really easily because their life cycle is longer than an Activity, for example.

Answer (score -1):

Yeap ... toast has to be displayed on the UI thread. When you don't return a result from doInBackground you can return a Boolean instead and use it in onPostExecute to show your Toast. onPostExecute is executed on the UI thread. runOnUIThread is also a solution ...

Comment: Because `AsyncTask` provides a mechanism to interact with the UI `Thread`.  `runOnUiThread()` posts a `Runnable` to the UI `Thread` `MessageQueue`.

Comment: True ... But I still really can't see what is wrong about it. You are in a different thread and you want to do something on UI thread, you use runOnUiThread... It's true it can be done different way in this case but it will work and it's not really bad.

Comment: That is the issue. You should not use `runOnUiThread()` because the framework is already giving you a way to interact with the UI Thread that does not require posting another `Runnable`